# Force Primefaces update from javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, primefaces

I have this problem:

on the page load I add an event listener 'keypress' on every input component in the page. I need to check the input if it contains some special characters and remove them.

This is the function launched on page load:

```
function activateCharsCheck() {
    var fields = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');
    if (fields) for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) { 
        addEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
    }
}
```

this is the function associated to keypress:

```
function handleKeyPress(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var cp = e.charCode;
    if (!cp) return
    var c = String.fromCharCode(cp);
    if (validChar(cp)){
        insert(e.target, c);
    // Here I need something to force update
    } else {
        PF('popupWarning').show();
    }   
}
```

and this is an example of input type:

```
<p:inputText id="myText" value="#{myBBean.text}">
   <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{myCBean.method()}" update="@form">
</p:inputText>
```

When I insert a character and the function is triggered, the ajax update doesn't work. If I refresh the page i lose the content or if there is a listener associated it doesn't start. Even the getter and setter don't work.

Some suggestion?
I'm searching for a method to force that ajax update or if there is another way to do this.

I think the problem is the function *insert(e.target, c);* that modify the content and conflicts with ajax  update.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml and https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/keyFilter.xhtml

Comment: Why do you have **always**  do `e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); `? Does it make a difference only doing this in the 'else/popup' part?

Comment: @JasperdeVries Unfortunately I have too many input text and I can't put the keyFilter for each of them, but the result I want it's that

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje, I found that the problem is that! Without e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); ajax update is correctly called. I tried your suggestion and it works now! Thansk a lot!

Comment: Please answer your own question if you've found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

```
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();
```

that prevent the ajax update.

This is the solution:

```
function handleKeyPress(e) {
    var cp = e.charCode;
    if (!cp) return
    var c = String.fromCharCode(cp);
    if (!validChar(cp)){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault(); 
        PF('popupWarning').show();
    }   
}
```

Thanks to @Kukeltje for the suggestion.